# How to subtract 18 hours from SYSDATETIME()

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to get a day and 1/2 less than the current time. In Oracle this works fine, however I get an error when doing this in Microsoft.

Here is my code:

```
and dataDate.DateValue > SYSDATETIME() - 1.5
```

my error:

```
Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with numeric
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to subtract 18 hours, use `dateadd()`:

```
select dateadd(hour, -18, sysdatetime())
```

Note that your code in Oracle subtracts 36 hours, not 18 hours.

Comment: Thank you, I figured this out just as you answered me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  select DATEADD(HOUR, -18,GETDATE())
```

Just worked good for me as well!